# class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { SIGABIRT ERROR in SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I got this error and I do not know why?
I have started learning swift today

```
2016-06-28 02:40:03.393 Calculator[7072:173608] -[Calculator.ViewController touchDigit]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc4a9465000
2016-06-28 02:40:03.400 Calculator[7072:173608] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Calculator.ViewController touchDigit]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc4a9465000'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100c40e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102980deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100c4948d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100b9690a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100b964b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010145f194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001015ce6fc -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001015ce9c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001015cdaf8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001014ce49b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001014cf1d0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010147db66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000101457d97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100b6ca31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100b6295c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100b61e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000100b61828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000105256ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010145d610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  Calculator                          0x0000000100a6361d main + 109
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010348992d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

My main class has only this simple method don't know what's happening

```
import UIKit

internal class ViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBAction internal func touchDigit(sender: UIButton)
}
```

Thank you

Comment: When posting a question, put a little thought into it. You just cut and pasted code with zero formatting or review of punctuation, etc. What's in the `touchDigit` method?

Answer (score 2):

Try unbinding your action in your storyboard/xib, and then rebinding it.

I'm guessing based on the missing `:` in the error (it should be `[ViewController touchDigit:]` since there is an argument), you added the argument `sender` *after* setting it up in your storyboard.

I just tested this myself, and when rebinding it, the storyboard shows it as `touchDigitWithSender`, even though it keeps the name `touchDigit`. Possibly some weird Swift/Objective-C interoperability thing.

---

P.S. `internal` is the default access specifier and you don't have to add it to every declaration

Comment: Very useful answer - I've just updated my project to Swift 3 and have been sat wondering why the first button press now crashes the app. This fixed it.